# What's a good API for creating music via programming?

Tags: procedural-music

I'm looking into playing around with procedurally generating music. I'm hoping to find a really a simple API where I can just call out instrument, note, duration and string together a song (I'll take anything of course, but that would be my preference). Is there any library that does this?

Comment: I am impressed to see that a question like this one is not down voted and not flag like "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". If the author had 1 reputation point, I'm sure everyone would have told him to ask his question on StackExchange instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet is a music programming environment, of which there are several.

[Csound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csound) is one of the best known ones. Here is their [website](http://www.csounds.com/).

[Max MSP](http://www.cycling74.com/products/max5) is also another widely used option, and it provides a visual programming interface too. It is, however, commercial.

Another well known option (and widely used by experimental electronic musicians) is [SuperCollider.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperCollider) [This](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/) is its webpage.

Here's a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_audio_synthesis_environments) describing similar languages/environments.

You can also use a general programming language with the right libraries to do audio/music work. Java, for one, provides the [Java Sound API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/).

Comment: Good call on CSound, I had forgotten about that. I know BT used it to do one of the songs on his This Binary Universe album: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Binary_Universe

Comment: Max/MSP is sourced from Pure Data, an open-source project by Miller Puckette. See: http://www-crca.ucsd.edu/~msp/software.html

Answer (score 3):

[JFugue](http://www.JFugue.org) was developed specifically to support procedural generation of music. It's a free, open-source (LGPL) Java API.

Comment: Anyone know of any non-LGPL options?

Comment: The newest version of JFugue, now in beta, uses Apache License 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give specific recommendations, since you didn't specify a language. Most languages have a decent [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midi) library though, that would be the first place I would look, unless you need something heavier than the MIDI format allows.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at  [Common Music](http://commonmusic.sourceforge.net).
It's a music composition system that transforms high-level algorithmic representations of musical processes and structure into a variety of control protocols for sound synthesis and display

Comment: This is a common lisp implementation you are linking to. Nothing about music on that page. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Generative music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_music) is a good start.
[Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=procedurally+generating+music&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) leads a couple interesting links, too. [Brian Eno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Eno#Generative_music) created procedurally generated music for Spore.