# Streaming programmatically generated audio to browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying write a web application that takes information from the user, generates audio on the server from that information, and then plays it back in the user's browser. I've been googling a whole bunch, and I'm kind of unsure exactly what it is that I need to do to get this to happen. What is it that programs like Icecast are doing "behind the scenes" to create these streams? I feel a little bit like I don't even know how to ask the right question or search as almost all the information I'm finding is either about serving files or assumes I know more than I do about how the server side of things works.

Comment: any code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This question may help with how to generate music programmatically; it suggests several tools that are designed for this purpose: [What's a good API for creating music via programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850412/whats-a-good-api-for-creating-music-via-programming)

Icecast is a bit of a red herring - that is the tool to broadcast an audio stream, so really you'd be looking at feeding the output of whatever tool you use to generate your music into Icecast or something similar in order to broadcast it to the world at large.  However, this is more for situations where you want a single stream to be broadcast to multiple users (e.g. internet radio).  If you simply want to generate audio from user input and serve it back to that user, then this isn't necessary.

I'm aware this isn't a full answer, as the question is not fully formed, but I couldn't fit it all into a comment.  Hopefully it should help others who stumble upon this question... I suspect the original question writer has moved on by now.

Answer (score -1):

Just have look at Media source API( under implementation). this would be what you are required.

```
window.MediaSource = window.MediaSource || window.WebKitMediaSource;

var ms = new MediaSource();

var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms);

ms.addEventListener('webkitsourceopen', function(e) {
  ...
  var sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('type; codecs="codecs"');
  sourceBuffer.append(oneAudioChunk); //append chunks of data 
  ....
}, false);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm asking for. this is client side -- I am trying to generate media SERVER SIDE and then server it to the client

Comment: so you want complete code for your app? dont think that developers do your work, its not the community to serve you. its for Q&A

Comment: No, that is not what I want. I actually don't want any code at all -- I'm looking for a conceptual answer.